# Find $f'(0)$ for $f(x)=(2x+1)^3(3x+3)^2$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $f'(0)$ for $f(x)=(2x+1)^3(3x+3)^2$.

Do I use the chain rule for each or do I use the derivative product rule first

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write $f$ as a product of two functions $g$ and $h$, where $g(x) = (2x + 1)^3$ and $h(x) = (3x + 3)^3$. Then

$$f' = (gh)' = g' h + g h'$$

by the product rule. It now just remains to find $g'$ and $h'$, which are done using the chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $f$ is a polynomial and so $f'(0)$ is it's coefficient of the term $x$. We needn't expand $f$ but just guess the coefficient knowing that
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3\quad\text{and}\quad (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
hence we see that 
$$f'(0)=(3\times2\times3^2)+(1^3\times6\times 3)=72$$

Comment: Teaching like a good teacher, Sami +)

Comment: A good teacher, indeed! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = (2x+1)^3\cdot (3x+3)^3$ and $f(0) = 27$

Taking $\log_{e}$ on both side

$\log_{e}f(x) = \log\left\{(2x+1)^3 \cdot (3x+3)^3\right\} = 3\cdot \log_{e}(2x+1)+3\cdot \log_{e}(3x+3)$

Now Diff. both side w.r.to $x$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot f^{'}(x) = \frac{3}{2x+1}\cdot 2+\frac{3}{3x+3}\cdot 3$

Put $x = 0$ on both side,

$\displaystyle \frac{f^{'}(0)}{27} = \frac{6}{1}+\frac{9}{3} = 9$

So $f^{'}(0) = 27 \times 9 = 243$